# How To Max Alphabate Character from table?

Tags: oracle

I have the following data and a massive problem:
in oracle database 
I have some data in table like this ..

```
id   version  article 
1      A       B001
2      B       B001 
3      C       B001
4      AA      B001
5      AB      B001
6      Z       B001
7      D       B001
```

I want to max version  from this table..

```
Select MAX(version) from  articles Where article = 'B001'
```

it gives 'Z' result which is wrong

but I want 'AB'

Answer (score 2):

```
with tab(id, version, article) as ( select 1 ,'A', 'B001' from dual union all 
       select 2, 'B', 'B001' from dual union all 
       select 3, 'C', 'B001' from dual union all 
       select 4, 'AA', 'B001' from dual union all 
       select 5, 'AB', 'B001' from dual union all 
       select 6, 'Z', 'B001' from dual union all 
       select 7, 'D', 'B001' from dual)
select  trim(max(lpad(version,3,' '))) ver from tab  where article = 'B001'
group by article;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two steps, 1) compare the length and 2) choose the maximum of them :

```
SELECT MAX(t.version) FROM articles t
WHERE article = 'B0001'
  AND length(t.version) = (SELECT max(length(s.version)) FROM articles s
                           WHERE s.article = 'B0001')
```

If you want it dynamic for all articles :

```
SELECT t.article, MAX(t.version) FROM articles t
WHERE 
  length(t.version) = (SELECT max(length(s.version)) FROM articles s
                       WHERE s.article = t.article)
GROUP BY t.article
```

Comment: hello dear still these query giving me Max version is 'Z'

but i want the result is 'AB'

Comment: @RaviKumar That's weird, are you sure you are using it correctly? exactly data like you posted? This should work. The sub query make sure that this is the longest string.

Comment: yes dear now work actually in table version is a character type field when is use trim than it works..